# PHP: regular expression to replace from a string everything except for alpha numeric characters

Tags: php, regex

I need to clean a string and make sure it contains alpha numeric characters only. I've come up with the following code that for some reason fails

```
    $string = 'aaa`bbb!!';
    $string = preg_replace("#[^a-zA-z0-9]*#", "", $string);
    echo $string;die;
```

The output I receive is aaa`bbb while I expect aaabbb. Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 10):

It should be a capital Z:

```
preg_replace("#[^a-zA-Z0-9]*#", "", $string);
```

When you write `A-z` it means all the characters between `A` (ASCII value 65) and `z` (ASCII value 122). This includes backtick (ASCII value 96) plus a few others that you didn't want (underscore, square brackets, backslash and tilde).

You can also use a `+` instead of a `*` to save repeatedly replacing the empty string with the empty string.

Comment: Or use the i flag for case-insensitive: preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9]*#i", "", $string);

Answer (score 3):

I think the `*` is unnecessary and you could simplify with `\W`. Just try the following:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[\W_]/", "", $string);
```

Also, if you merely want to validate - check out `ctype_alnum`. It avoids the overhead of the RegEx library.

Comment: This currently allows underscore - can remove that also with either `\W|_` or `[\W_]` as the expression.

Comment: @Peter. Good point about the underscore. I have updated my expression.